# Spring Data- MongoRepository : Can we have binary type as the _id?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a class that represents a Mongo collection called "archive"

```
@Document(collection = "archive")

public class Message{
    @Id
    private byte[] messageId;

    private String from;
    private String to;
    // more stuff

}
```

The interface MessagesRepository extends MongoRepository:

```
public interface MessagesRepository extends MongoRepository<Message, String>{

}
```

Through an API call, I get a `findMessage` request, which gives me a `messageId` in `String`. I will then need to encode it into byte[] and then invoke `messagesRepository.findOne()` method. ( Remember the ID is `byte[]` ).

It fails. It returns `null`. I guess because the `byte []` stored in Mongo would be different from the `byte[]` within the `findOne()` method since different strings even with same values produce different `byte[]` arrays.

How can I make this work? Or is it really possible to work with _id in binary?

Comment: What is the logical data type of the ID field?

Comment: @chrylis: OP said it is byte[]; @"Sasanka Panguluri": you are not doing yourself a favor by using binary/bytes for _id; why not use the message String or its hashCode instead?

Comment: @Seismoid There's a reason I asked about the **logical** type. It's obvious that the immediately declared type is `byte[]`. And using `hashCode` is absurd; database IDs need to be unique.

Comment: @chrylis: yes, hasCode was a bad one, sorry. he says he gets a string `messageId`, so i guess he creates his byte array from that string somehow; i just wonder why the string is not good enough...

Comment: @chrylis The original type is String. the messageId is actually a UUID, which if stored in Mongo in binary encoded format would save me space.

Comment: @Seismoid Please see my comment above; String isn't good enough since it's a UUID.

Comment: So why not use `UUID`?

Comment: It eats a lot of space in Mongo. I've read at several places it's good to store UUIDs in binary encoded formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it still worked. I was able to have a `byte[]` as the `_id`. I was able to successfully insert and retrieve stuff. The problem with `find()` is in MongoRepository. It needs to be adjusted to make it work.

See : http://pastebin.com/xHVQJYfN

EDIT : I got the latest driver and it worked straight away.

Answer (score 0):

you are not doing yourself a favor by using `byte[]`as an id.

you say you get a messageId as a `String` - why not use that? otherwise you might just end up casting between string and bytes types (unless the use of `byte[]`is not by your own choice, but an constraint given to you). you noticed yourself that the bytes generated even from equal strings don't match.

short example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s1 = "hello";
    String s2 = "hello";

    System.out.println("our two strings: ");
    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);

    // one of the first thing we learned when starting with
    // java was that this is not equal
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("compare with ==");
    if(s1==s2) System.out.println("equal");
    else System.out.println("not equal");

    // but this is equal
    System.out.println("compare with equals()");
    if(s1.equals(s2)) System.out.println("equal");
    else System.out.println("not equal");

    // create the byte arrays and compare them
    byte[] b1 = s1.getBytes();
    byte[] b2 = s2.getBytes();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("byte array 1: " + b1.toString());
    System.out.println("byte array 2: " + b2.toString());

    // same as for strings
    System.out.println("compare with ==");
    if(b1==b2) System.out.println("equal");
    else System.out.println("not equal");

    // not equal, unlike the strings from which we
    // created the byte arrays
    System.out.println("compare with equals()");
    if(b1.equals(b2)) System.out.println("equal");
    else System.out.println("not equal");


    // create string out of the bytes again and compare
    String ss1 = new String(b1, "UTF-8");
    String ss2 = new String(b2, "UTF-8");

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("re-created string 1: " + ss1);
    System.out.println("re-created string 2: " + ss2);

    // this is equal again
    System.out.println("compare re-created strings with equals()");
    if(ss1.equals(ss2)) System.out.println("equal");
    else System.out.println("not equal");
}
```

that's why i ask why it has to be bytes; it's making everything HARDER, not easier.

Comment: That's right, thank you. But what else can I do to save space in my Mongo?